# WPF application does not ask Firewall for permission

Tags: c#, wpf, release, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm making a WPF application where I use WebCLient to download file from a webserver. When I startup my app in debug mode it asks Firewall for permission and then I allow it to, which make my app works as it should.

But in release mode it does not prompt me with Firewall permission, which makes my app crash when downloading a file. I deploy my app in release mode. When I run the `.exe` file I get after deployment it still does not ask for Firewall permission which makes my app work incorrectly.

Is there a way to trigger Firewall prompt, maybe programmatically, in release mode?

Comment: This may be relevant : http://superuser.com/questions/115667/how-do-i-get-the-windows-7-firewall-to-prompt-me-whether-to-allow-or-deny-a-new

Comment: I wonder why your get a Firewall prompt at all - WebClient uses an outgoing connection which by default is not blocked, so I suspect your application is crashing for another reason, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Must read**: I have searched for a way to request firewall access using C# but couldn't find anything relevant or safe..The batch is 100% clean and will not be detected as any sort of malware.(I couldn't find a way to do it in C# this is not off-topic!)

I don't know much about requesting to add an allow rule, but I know how to add a rule:
**Just for inbound:**

**1) Start notepad and type:**

```
@echo off
setlocal
set RULENAME="SomethingSpecial"
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=%RULENAME% >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 ( goto :EOF) else (
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SomethingSpecial" dir=in action=allow program="DIRECTORY" enable=yes) 
goto :EOF
```

**2) Replace SomethingSpecial** with anything you want . It is just a name and if you replace it, replace it everywhere(you can keep SomethingSpecial as it is)

**3) Replace DIRECTORY** with your Release build directory (e.g: `C:\program files\something.exe`)
**dir** means direction set to in because you are downloading. 
**for both directions** type this:

```
 @echo off
setlocal
set RULENAME="SomethingSpecial"
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=%RULENAME% >nul
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 ( goto :EOF) else (
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SomethingSpecial" dir=in action=allow program="DIRECTORY" enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SomethingSpecial" dir=out action=allow program="DIRECTORY" enable=yes) 
goto :EOF
```

**Save in .bat format and remember path**

Now the fun part..

In your applications use below code .. If your program doesn't run as admin and you don't want Users to keep giving permissions find a way to run the process only once...Maybe save to a file, boolean or string and check it at program startup once so that the program doesn't run the bat process thing everytime.

```
 ProcessStartInfo bat = new ProcessStartInfo();
    bat.Verb = "runas";
    bat.FileName = "BatchDirectory";
    bat.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process.Start(bat);
```

**Replace BatchDirectory** with your batch directory (use '/' not '\' just here)

Have fun!
 Comment if you have a question or if you have a problem.

Comment: I am struggling with this issue as well. I do not understand how your solution solved the problem. I added a rule by hand, but it didnt solve the problem